# git clone for go.googlesource.com fails on machine behind proxy

Tags: git, go

I'm trying to clone go package (golang.org/x/text/language, stored on go.googlesource.com) on a RHEL6 server behind a corporate proxy but the go get command fails:

```
> go get -v golang.org/x/text/language
Fetching https://golang.org/x/text/language?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/text/language?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/text/language": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/text", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/text"} at https://golang.org/x/text/language?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/text/language": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/text?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/text?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/text (download)
# cd .; git clone https://go.googlesource.com/text /local/home/me/dev/src/golang.org/x/text
Cloning into '/local/home/me/dev/src/golang.org/x/text'...
error: HTTP response code said error while accessing https://go.googlesource.com/text/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
package golang.org/x/text/language: exit status 128
```

I'm pretty sure this is related to git not being able to clone as the following command also fails:

```
git clone --verbose https://go.googlesource.com/text
Cloning into 'text'...
error: HTTP response code said error while accessing https://go.googlesource.com/text/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I have set proxies both in my shell environment and for git (http and https) and they are working, as you can see here:

```
wget https://go.googlesource.com/text
--2017-07-04 11:17:15--  https://go.googlesource.com/text
Resolving our.proxy.host ... 10.4.xxx.xxx
Connecting to our.proxy.host|10.4.xxx.xxx|:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: “text”

    [ <=>                                                                               ] 11,014      --.-K/s   in 0.02s

2017-07-04 11:17:15 (622 KB/s) - “text” saved [11014]
```

go get also seems to work fine, as I'm not getting any problems executing

```
go get github.com/stretch/testify
```

Any clues as to what might be the problem are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Georg

Comment: What is the output of `go get -v golang.org/x/text/language`?

Comment: Just added the output to the original question, @icza

Comment: Did you try `git config --global http.https://go.googlesource.com.followRedirects true` ?

Comment: I have now @mattn - thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, that didn't change anything for me. I'm on a rather old git installation (1.7.11) and AFAIK, git stopped following redirects in a later version, didn't it?

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea. Sorry.

Comment: What is the output of `wget https://go.googlesource.com/text/info/refs`? Seems like maybe the first request is succeeding with 200 OK, but the request to look up the refs might be failing separately.

Comment: @orirawlings  here is the output ...  wget https://go.googlesource.com/text/info/refs
--2021-11-22 15:09:58--  https://go.googlesource.com/text/info/refs
Resolving go.googlesource.com (go.googlesource.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘go.googlesource.com’
   ....  I am getting same problem as above ...   `dig go.googlesource.com`  shows it has no dns registrar type A record so nothing can connect to that domain ... my VPS is in Germany however when using a USA server I see a type A record  for  domain

Comment: when logged onto a USA box I correctly get a dns type A record as per ...  dig go.googlesource.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> go.googlesource.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 964
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;go.googlesource.com.  IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
go.googlesource.com. 300 IN CNAME googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.
googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com. 60 IN A 173.194.207.82

Comment: .....  however below I run on a VPS in Germany and get  ...   dig go.googlesource.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> go.googlesource.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 10947
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;go.googlesource.com.  IN A

Comment: SOLUTIOn see  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32395  ... issue this before doing compile ...  go.googlesource.com is hosted by Google, which is having a large-scale outage right now. Since you're using modules, you might try setting GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org. proxy.golang.org is also hosted by Google, but seems to be tolerating the outage better.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

see  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32395

domain   go.googlesource.com is hosted by Google, which is having a large-scale outage right now. Since you're using modules, you might try setting

```
GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org
```

proxy.golang.org is also hosted by Google, but seems to be tolerating the outage better.

before issuing above GOPROXY command I could not compile golang source code from a vps in Germany ...

```
dig go.googlesource.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> go.googlesource.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 10947
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;go.googlesource.com.       IN  A

;; Query time: 448 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 22 15:14:46 CET 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48
```

notice in above domain  `go.googlesource.com` incorrectly does not have a type A record ... whereas below I run on a USA machine which is fine

```
 dig go.googlesource.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> go.googlesource.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44718
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;go.googlesource.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
go.googlesource.com.    300 IN  CNAME   googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.
googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com. 183 IN A    173.194.175.82

;; Query time: 47 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 22 09:26:52 EST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 109
```